# QScrollBar adding space in a vertical Layout

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I am getting an issue regarding QScrollbar as it is adding about 3px space just above the scrollBar, which is actually not required. QGraphicsview width increases 3px added above.

We have a vertical layout. After the zoom is applied in LinearGraphics scrollbar width increases and 3px space is added above it.

I am attaching images for reference:

[image: Scroll Bar without Space added before Zoom]

[image: ScrollBar with Space added after zoom]
[image: This is default image without Space is added and when stylesheet is applied the default width remain there]
How to remove this space?

Comment: Try to find the widget which adds the margin to the layout and remove it.

Comment: This is a QScrollBar issue I have tried to evaluate it with the Other Widget but this issue is of Scroll Bar. When I have removed the StyleSheet of ScrollBar  i.e Default Scroll Bar it comes with default width using styleSheet I am able to reduce the height of ScrollBar but default space is remain there I am not able to remove that space after decreasing  the minimum height of the scroll Bar..

Comment: Then you should file some bug report at https://bugreports.qt.io/.